# Using QGIS' "network protocol" to import data from OPeNDAP?

Tags: qgis, raster, wfs, ascii, opendap

After looking at the OPeNDAP documentation
I assumed I could import data into QGIS by downloading the .ascii file OPeNDAP generates. However the downloaded OPeNDAP .ascii doesn't seem to be compatible with the ERSI .asc import methods on QGIS.  [This website](https://www.dataone.org/software-tools/quantum-gis-qgis) says that you can import OPeNDAP and GeoJSON vector data via QGIS "network protocol" but future searches on google and the QGIS documentation (module 11 online resources) hasn't helped.

Does accessing data via network protocol mean using the Add WFS function of QGIS?

Can you only open OPeNDAP vector data and not raster data on QGIS?

This is the ascii [file](http://cida.usgs.gov/thredds/dodsC/CA-BCM-2014/historical.ascii?x[0:1:3485],y[0:1:4476],time[0:1:1379],HST_Monthly_aet[0:1:0][0:1:0][0:1:0],HST_Monthly_cwd[0:1:0][0:1:0][0:1:0],HST_Monthly_exc[0:1:0][0:1:0][0:1:0],HST_Monthly_pet[0:1:0][0:1:0][0:1:0],HST_Monthly_ppt[0:1:0][0:1:0][0:1:0],HST_Monthly_str[0:1:0][0:1:0][0:1:0]) I need from OPeNDAP. It should be a "Basin Characterization Model" that is a raster with multiple layers.

Does anyone have experience getting data from OPeNDAP into QGIS?

Comment: I suppose it would need QGIS with a GDAL version that is compiled with OPenDAP driver http://www.gdal.org/frmt_dods.html. It is not compiled by default http://www.gdal.org/formats_list.html.

Comment: I installed libdap (http://www.opendap.org/winPort) since it is needed to compile DODS for gdal. Any idea how I would recompile gdal with DODS now that I installed libdap?